# Different tabName in SideBar and TabItems

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

In my `shinydashboard` app, I want to specify a different tabName in the `sidebarMenu` from the tabName in the `body`. The server function should then catch the tabName on click and call `updateTabItems`.

The idea is, that some menu items in the sidebar should go to the same tab, and the longer tabName  in the sideBar contains additional information used to fill the tab.

When both tabNames in sideBar and tabItems are the same, the code works. However, if I change the tabName in the sideBar, e.g. to `one_param_val`, `updateTabItems` stops working.

Any ideas why that is and what I can do about it?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(
    header=shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(title = "Switch tabs"),
    sidebar=shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
        shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
            shinydashboard::menuItem(
                "Menu Item 1", tabName = "one_param_val" # works for tabName="one"
            ),
            shinydashboard::menuItem(
                "Menu Item 2", tabName = "two"
            )
        )
    ),
    body=shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
        shinydashboard::tabItems(
            shinydashboard::tabItem(
                tabName = "one", h2("Content One")
            ),
            shinydashboard::tabItem(
                tabName = "two", h2("Content Two")
            )
        )   
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    shiny::observeEvent(input$tabs, {
        if(grepl("^one", input$tabs)) {
            message("switching to one")
            shinydashboard::updateTabItems(
                session, inputId="tabs", selected="one"
            )
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please see `?tabItem`: tabName: The name of a tab. This *must correspond* to the tabName of a menuItem or menuSubItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround using a `hidden` `menuItem`. However the proxy `menuItem` will no longer get marked as selected in the sidebar:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(
  header=shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(title = "Switch tabs"),
  sidebar=shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
    shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                shinyjs::hidden(shinydashboard::menuItem(
                                  "Menu Item 1", tabName = "one"
                                )),
                                shinydashboard::menuItem(
                                  "Menu Item 1", tabName = "one_param_val"
                                ),
                                shinydashboard::menuItem(
                                  "Menu Item 2", tabName = "two"
                                )
    )
  ),
  body=shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    shinydashboard::tabItems(
      shinydashboard::tabItem(
        tabName = "one", h2("Content One")
      ),
      shinydashboard::tabItem(
        tabName = "two", h2("Content Two")
      )
    )   
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  shiny::observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    # browser()
    if(grepl("^one", input$tabs)) {
      message("switching to one")
      shinydashboard::updateTabItems(
        session, inputId="tabs", selected="one"
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```